# Running a interaction matrix between many variables

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, interaction

I have a data set with 70 column variables, each is 0-1 dummy variable, and 3500 observations. I am looking to see how often observations with a 'success' in one variable are matched with another variable. In other words it obs 1 has a success dummy in variable one how often does it also have a success in variable 2 and so on for all the variables. I have found how to create a matrix table showing interactions when only two columns are involved however i cant find anything involving many columns. Ideally id like to present this in an interaction matrix with 70 variables across and 70 down. Here is an idea of the data set:

`Dat A   B   C   D
 XX 1   1   1   1
 XY 0   1   0   1
 XZ 0   0   1   1`

The output im hoping for would be:

```
Out A   B   C   D
A   0   1   1   1
B       0   1   2
C           0   2
D               0
```

Showing the number of times that (A,B) is a pairing (B,C) is a pairing and so on.

I have tried using the table() command as well as as.matrix but it seems these require data organized as two columns and cannot understand the data when it refers to many column variables. I am fairly new to R so I apologize if my question isnt clear or is possibly quite simple.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please provide a small reproducible dataset and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry new to asking these questions. I added some more info to make things more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to create a correlation matrix of indefinite size. First create a reproducible example of your dataset...

```
dat <- matrix(sample(0:1, size = 700, replace = TRUE), ncol = 70)
dat <- data.frame(dat)
```

Then calculate the correlation...

```
dat <- cor(dat)
```

And then plot the correlation visually...

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(dat, method = "square")
```

[image: A massive correlation matrix with colored squares]

You can also plot the correlation using numbers instead of colors...

```
corrplot(dat, method = "number")
```

[image: A massive correlation matrix with numbers]

Obviously you'll want to finesse these charts before using them in a publication. `corrplot` offers tons of options for chart appearance.

Comment: This is helpful but not quite what i was looking for i think my question wasnt clear enough. I added some more to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
res <- apply(combn(2:ncol(df), 2), 2, function(x, y) sum(rowSums(y[, x]) == 2), df)
m <- diag(x=0, ncol(df)-1)
m[upper.tri(m)] <- res
m[lower.tri(m)] <- NA
dimnames(m) <- list(colnames(df)[-1], colnames(df)[-1])
   A  B  C D
A  0  1  1 1
B NA  0  1 2
C NA NA  0 2
D NA NA NA 0
```